# What should we use as source control with TFS in Visual Studio(TFS source control plugin or VisualSVN )?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visualsvn

We are planning to use Team Foundation Server, but we need to decide whether to use the Visual Studio Team Foundation Server source control plugin or the VisualSVN source control plugin inside Visual Studio.

Comment: If you planned to use TFS, why not using its Source Control feature and go for SVN instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you plan to use TFS, go for the TFS Source Control, feature-wise it's as good as SVN if not better (history is managed the same way, branches too, perfs are better).

But where you get benefits in the TFS Source Control compared with SVN is in the integration with Work Item and the rest of TFS.

When you work on a given Task Work Item you can associate your check-ins (then changeset) with the Task, and it's very powerful because you'll have a more project based view than code view.

The Source Control of TFS is the lowest layer of the ALM Solution, you can avoid using it, but you'll lose a lot of things (integration with Work Item, Continuous Integration, Reports, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

If you are planning to use Team Foundation Server, then use visual studio team foundation server source control plugin.

Comment: Can you elaborate with comparisons?